# Django/Bootstrap modal won't appear on page load

Tags: jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a modal pop up when my page loads and nothing is appearing. I have tested this code outside of the {% if request.GET.logout %} and it still does not work. I am also certain that these blocks are being executed.

```
    {% if request.GET.logout %}
    {% block head-extras %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logout-modal').modal('show');
      });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
    <div class="modal" id="logout-modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Edit: This only works if I put

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
```

above the script for the $(document).ready. Is there a way to not have to do this? Bootstrap recommends that I should load the jquery before the closing body tag.

Comment: I would suggest you to put your JavaScript in a separate file and load that file in your parent (layout) template after you load jQuery (all before closing body tag).

Comment: Based on the block name, I'm guessing that code appears in the `<head>` section? Visible content can't go there. Keep the js snippet there and move the modal div inside the `<body>`.

Comment: The block goes in the body but that small segment within head-extras goes in the head